how to correctly use \enumitem or \enumitem-zref for referencing a bullet point
Hi there I was looking for a possible alternative to cross-reference a bullet point in-text in my report document. Currently, I'm doing as follow:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=electricultramarine,
    filecolor=.,
    linkcolor=maroon,
    urlcolor=smokyblack,
    linktoc=all
}
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.69, 0.19, 0.38}
\definecolor{smokyblack}{rgb}{0.06, 0.05, 0.03}
\definecolor{ceruleanblue}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}
\definecolor{electricultramarine}{rgb}{0.25, 0.0, 1.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item description 1
    \item description 2 \label{item:2}
\end{itemize}

\newpage

\dots This entire process is relatively easy, as taken care by a custom-made \texttt{R} script, which acts on the BED coordinate file already pre-processed for demographic inference modelling (\textit{see} \hyperref[item:2]{\textcolor{ceruleanblue}{\textbf{point 2}}}). \dots

\end{document}

but I wonder whether there is a way to have the text point 2 shown up in the sentence without having to resort to \hyperref[item:2]{\textcolor{ceruleanblue}{\textbf{point 2}}}.
Maybe a more efficient alternative using the package \enumitem or \enumitem-zref, as I've seen in some posts. Unfortunately, the best I could get was showing up just the number 2 without additional text.
If anyone has more experience, or any advice, on how to do this so that I have some options to work with also for lists, I'll be glad to try. Thanks in advance!

You should probably use enumerate rather than itemize if you want to generate a "point 2"  reference as no counting happens with itemize

@DavidCarlisle I see, I will fix that; I actually though was there was a way by using the \enumitem. Thanks again!

It's not impossible. It just doesn't make sense. What does it mean to a reader to be told 'see point 2' if there is no '2' to be seen?

The enumitem way is to use enumerate and to change the format of the label to show a counter and the format of ref to show a number.

@cfr, thanks a lot that makes sense conceptually; I moved on and fixed it. Thanks Ulrike Fischer for the insights on how \enumitem works!
